# if..else statement giving Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, if-statement, na

My code is as follows:

```
if (as.numeric(income[1,6]) < as.numeric(income[1,5])){
  wotrans<- round(-(as.numeric(income[1,6])/as.numeric(income[1,5]))^(1/5),2)
}
else{
  wotrans<- round((as.numeric(income[1,6])/as.numeric(income[1,5])-1)^(1/5),2)
}
```

But it keeps throwing this error:

```
Error in if (as.numeric(income[1, 6]) < as.numeric(income[1, 5])) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I dont see how TRUE/FALSE is missing because when i try

```
as.numeric(income[1,6])<as.numeric(income[1,5])
```

I get TRUE or FALSE outcomes
income[1,6] and income[1,5] are integers in a data.frame

Comment: It would help to have a reproducible example. Can we have `head(income, 3)`?

Comment: It seems highly likely that you do a comparison with `NA`. Try to us an`if(is.na())` check before your `if/else` construct you show so you catch any `NA` occurring at run-time.

Comment: @us3r11852 you're right! thank you.